# how to identify the same product name in a table in a visual force page

Tags: visualforce

Can any one help me outhow to identify the same product name  in a table  in a visual force page which is in a PDF format .

For Example : Here the Product Name as "BXRC-25e4000-F-04" appears twice in a Quarter for the months Jan and Feb.Now the Quantity & Amount Should get Added displayed at one place and the product name should get appeared only once.

Any help is very much appreciated .

**Code :**

```
if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name)){
                    w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);
                    w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod_Amount;
                } else {
                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                }
```

**Complete Code :**

```
public with sharing class QuoteContentController {

    public Competitor__c com{get;set;}
    public gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c opflist{get;set;}
    public Id qId {get;set;}
    public string all{get;set;}

    //Declare a wrapper class  

    public class Wrapperclass{

    //custom wrapper datatype  

        public string Name{get;set;}  
        public string AccountType{get;set;}  
        public date todaysDate{get;set;}  
        public date Expected_Order_Date{get;set;}
        public string Probability{get;set;}  
        public string Internal_Comment{get;set;}  
        public string External_Comment{get;set;}  

        public string Segment{get;set;}  
        public string Application{get;set;}  
        public string Persona{get;set;}  
        public string Geogrpahy{get;set;}  

        public string PartNumbers{get;set;}  
        public Decimal  Price{get;set;}  
        public Decimal End_Customer_Price{get;set;}  
        public Decimal Quantity {get;set;}  
        public Decimal Total{get;set;}  

        public string RFQ_justification{get;set;}  
        public string Main_Customer_of_Account{get;set;}  
        public string Bridgelux_competition_at_account{get;set;}
        public string Geographic_regions_serviced{get;set;}  
        public string Annual_lighting_revenue{get;set;}  
        public string Annual_LED_revenue_or_percent{get;set;}  
        public string Annual_purchases_of_LED_light_sources{get;set;}
        public string Percent_of_LED_purchases_that_are_COB{get;set;}  
        public string Other_information{get;set;}  

        public string Product_Series{get;set;}  
        public string Volume{get;set;} 
        public string Date_Price_is_Valid{get;set;} 

        public string gmod_Opportunity{get;set;}
        public string gmod_Product{get;set;}
        public Decimal gmod_Quantity{get;set;}
        public Decimal gmod_Price{get;set;}
        public Decimal gmod_Quarter{get;set;}
        public Decimal gmod_Month{get;set;}
        public Decimal gmod_Amount{get;set;}
        public Decimal Actual_Price{get;set;}
        public Decimal  gmod_Year{get;set;}
        public Date gmod_date{get;set;}
        public string gmod_Month_Text{get;set;}
        public Date  Forecast_Date{get;set;}

        public wrapperClass(){} 
    }

    public QuoteContentController(){}

    public QuoteContentController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        qId=Apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        disp_Map = new Map<String,wrapperClass>();
    }

    public Integer subtotalofquantity{get;set;}
    public Integer subtotalofamount{get;set;}
    public Map<String,wrapperClass> disp_Map{get;set;}
    public List<wrapperClass> disp_list {get;set;}{
        disp_list=new list<wrapperclass>();

        list<Quote> q =[select id ,Name ,QuoteNumber,Effective_Date__c ,Comments__c ,Quote.Opportunity.id, 
                    Quote.Opportunity.Probability ,Quote.Opportunity.AccSegment__c ,Quote.Opportunity.AccApplication__c,Quote.Opportunity.Persona__c,Quote.Opportunity.Region__c
                    from Quote where id=:apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id')];

        Opportunity opp =[select id , Name, (select id, Quantity, product2id from OpportunityLineItems), probability, AccSegment__c from Opportunity where opportunity.Id =:q[0].opportunity.id];

        list<gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c>  opflist = [Select id ,Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.id,gmod__Product__c,gmod__Quantity__c,gmod__Price__c , gmod__Month__c,    gmod__date__c,  gmod__Quarter__c ,gmod__Amount__c ,Actual_Price__c ,gmod__Year__c ,gmod__Month_Text__c ,Forecast_Date__c,gmod__Product__r.Name ,gmod__opportunity__r.name from gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c WHERE gmod__Product__c!=null and gmod__opportunity__r.id =:opp.id order by gmod__Month__c asc limit 9]; 
        for (Quote qt :q){
             System.debug('Quote Size ++ '+q.size());
             System.debug('opp forcast ++ ' +opflist.size());

            for(integer i=0;i<opflist.size();i++){
                subtotalofquantity += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                subtotalofamount  += integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);
                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();
                if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name)){
                    w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);
                    w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod_Amount;
                } else {
                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                }
                w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
                w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;
                w.Name =opflist[i].Name;
                w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;
                w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;
                w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;
                w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;
                w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;
                w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;
                w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;
                disp_Map.put(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name,w);
            }
        }
        for(wrapperclass w : disp_Map.values()){
            disp_list.add(w);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Use a wrapper, perform comparisons in apex, then display it in visualforce.

Comment: I don't know that there is enough to go on in this question, but this sounds like you need to do some kind of aggregate query to get what you want with a `GROUP BY` on Product name.

Comment: @Peter:I tried using the Group By function .It worked fine in Developer Console and throws Error in Controller.SELECT gmod__product__r.name ,SUm(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c,Sum(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c,COUNT(id) Quantity FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c GROUP BY gmod__product__r.name

Comment: @Bart Juriewicz;To get the details of custom object i have used wrapper class.I have updated the Complete code.Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead of your for loop

```
 if(opflist.size() > 0 )
           { 
            if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name)){
                    w = disp_Map.get(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name);
                    w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[0].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[0].gmod_Amount;
                } else {
                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[0].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[0]. gmod__Amount__c;
                }
 for(integer i=1;i<opflist.size();i++){
                subtotalofquantity += integer.valueOf(opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c);
                subtotalofamount  += integer.valueOf(opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c);
                wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();

   if(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name != opflist[i-1].gmod__Product__r.Name ){
              if(disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name )){
                    w = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name);
                    w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount = disp_Map.get(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Amount + opflist[i].gmod_Amount; 
               } else {
                    w.gmod_Quantity =opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;
                    w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                }
                w.gmod_Opportunity = opflist[i].gmod__Opportunity__r.Name;
                w.gmod_Product = opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name;
                w.Name =opflist[i].Name;
                w.gmod_Quarter=opflist[i].gmod__Quarter__c;
                w.gmod_Month=opflist[i].gmod__Month__c;
                w.gmod_Amount=opflist[i]. gmod__Amount__c;
                w.Actual_Price=opflist[i].Actual_Price__c;
                w.gmod_Year=opflist[i].gmod__Year__c;
                w.gmod_date=opflist[i].gmod__date__c;
                w.gmod_Month_Text=opflist[i].gmod__Month_Text__c;
                w.Forecast_Date=opflist[i].Forecast_Date__c;
                disp_Map.put(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name,w);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: :It throws an Error as : Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Boolean at line .The line is : w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[i].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[i].gmod__Quantity__c;

Comment: w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[0].gmod__Quantity__c; write zero instead i. Then assign i =1;  and put the above if condition

Comment: :I have made changes.But still i get the Same Error as :Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Boolean at line w.gmod_Quantity =disp_Map.containsKey(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name).gmod_Quantity + opflist[0].gmod__Quantity__c;I have updated the complete code.Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I have edited my answer try if it works.

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan:i get different types of errors as :If i use if(opflist.size() > 0 ) in the for loop it throws an Error as :Duplicate variable: i (attempt to re-create the variable with type: integer) at line 152 column 28.The throws as Variable does not exist: w at line 144 column 21. w = disp_Map.get(opflist[0].gmod__Product__r.Name);
At last it throws an Error as Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: exactly, put the    wrapperclass w = new wrapperclass();  over the if loop  and try again, or u can remove the  if(opflist.size() > 0 ) loop it is just for size checking.

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan:it gives an Error as :Visualforce Error
Attempt to de-reference a null object

Comment: Any line number ?

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan :For this Error as :Visualforce Error Attempt to de-reference a null object – no line numer

Comment: Check the debug log might be you have missed out instentiating some object or the list is empty on which you are performing functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21413/discussion-between-maruf-bagwan-and-nikkey).

Comment: @ Maruf Bagwan:i tried even in Debug logs .I still get the same error as Visualforce Error Attempt to de-reference a null object.Any help is very much appreciated.